# what are the logging options in azure api management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

What are the logging options in Azure API Management? From what I understand, Azure API Management can generate logging of errors that occur in it (like invalid subscription key, invalid endpoint, etc).  How can identify and configure loggable events in APIM?  How can that logging output be wired into a custom logging service hosted through APIM?

Comment: Seems duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371979/querying-azure-apim-diagnostic-logs/52382002#52382002

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's recommendation is to send the events to EventHub.  You can then process the events there and log them however you want.  This approach minimizes the performance impact of logging on your APIs.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-and-azure-event-hubs-integration/