# Querying Azure APIM Diagnostic Logs

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, ibm-api-management

I've enabled diagnostic logs for APIM which are being sent to log-analytics.
**Scenario**
All incoming requests to server have `RequestTracking_Id` header.
All backend services use `RequestTracking_Id` header from the request in logs to track the request. 
But from in APIM logs, I'm not able to pull this header to query upon.

Is there any way it is possible to have header information of incoming requests in APIM diagnostic logs?

Query:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Type contains "Azure" and Resource contains "APIM-DEV" and backendUrl_s contains "/relativePath" and DurationMs > 2000
```

The columns which are available on querying are :

> TenantId  SourceSystem    MG  ManagementGroupName TimeGenerated   Computer    activityId_g    requestResourceType_s   requestResourceId_s collectionRid_s statusCode_s    duration_s  clientIpAddress_s   requestCharge_s requestLength_s responseLength_s    resourceTokenUserRid_s  region_s    partitionId_g   error_number_d  Severity    user_defined_b  state_d exec_type_d wait_category_s total_query_wait_time_ms_d  max_query_wait_time_ms_d    is_parameterizable_s    statement_type_s    statement_key_hash_s    query_param_type_d  interval_start_time_d   interval_end_time_d logical_io_writes_d max_logical_io_writes_d physical_io_reads_d max_physical_io_reads_d logical_io_reads_d  max_logical_io_reads_d  execution_type_d    count_executions_d  cpu_time_d  max_cpu_time_d  dop_d   max_dop_d   rowcount_d  max_rowcount_d  query_max_used_memory_d max_query_max_used_memory_d duration_d  max_duration_d  num_physical_io_reads_d max_num_physical_io_reads_d log_bytes_used_d    max_log_bytes_used_d    query_id_d  query_hash_s    plan_id_d   query_plan_hash_s   statement_sql_handle_s  LogicalServerName_s ElasticPoolName_s   DatabaseName_s  start_utc_date_t    end_utc_date_t  wait_type_s delta_max_wait_time_ms_d    delta_signal_wait_time_ms_d delta_wait_time_ms_d    delta_waiting_tasks_count_d keyProperties_curve_s   keyProperties_operations_s  keyProperties_attributes_enabled_b  algorithm_s identity_claim_xms_mirid_s  lastError_transportErrorCode_d  subnetId_s  backendMethod_s backendUrl_s    backendResponseCode_d   backendTime_d   requestSize_d   productId_s userId_s    apimSubscriptionId_s    backendProtocol_s   secretProperties_attributes_enabled_b   clientIp_s  clientPort_s    ruleSetType_s   ruleSetVersion_s    ruleId_s    Message action_s    site_s  details_message_s   details_data_s  details_file_s  details_line_s  hostname_s  apiId_s operationId_s   apiRevision_s   clientIP_s  clientPort_d    httpMethod_s    requestQuery_s  userAgent_s httpStatus_d    httpVersion_s   receivedBytes_d sentBytes_d timeTaken_d sslEnabled_s    host_s  Level_d isRequestSuccess_b  location_s  lastError_source_s  lastError_reason_s  lastError_message_s lastError_section_s method_s    url_s   responseCode_d  responseSize_d  cache_s clientProtocol_s    lastError_elapsed_d clientTime_d    matchedConnections_d    systemId_g  vnetResourceGuid_g  subnetPrefix_s  macAddress_s    primaryIPv4Address_s    ruleName_s  direction_s type_s  instanceId_s    healthyHostCount_d  unHealthyHostCount_d    requestCount_d  latency_d   failedRequestCount_d    throughput_d    priority_d  conditions_protocols_s  conditions_sourcePortRange_s    conditions_destinationPortRange_s   conditions_destinationIP_s  conditions_sourceIP_s   conditions_None_s   trustedService_s    CorrelationId   identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_identity_claims_scope_s   isAccessPolicyMatch_b   certificateProperties_attributes_enabled_b  certificatePolicyProperties_certificateProperties_subject_s certificatePolicyProperties_certificateProperties_validityInMonths_d    certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_type_s    certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_size_d    certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_reuse_b   certificatePolicyProperties_keyProperties_export_b  certificatePolicyProperties_certificateIssuerProperties_name_s  certificateEnrollmentProperties_id_s    certificateEnrollmentProperties_certificateProperties_subject_s certificateEnrollmentProperties_certificateProperties_sha1_s    certificateEnrollmentProperties_certificateProperties_sha256_s  certificateEnrollmentProperties_certificateProperties_nbf_t certificateEnrollmentProperties_certificateProperties_exp_t certificateEnrollmentProperties_keyProperties_size_d    certificateEnrollmentProperties_keyProperties_type_s    certificateEnrollmentProperties_secretProperties_type_s certificateEnrollmentProperties_attributes_created_d    certificateEnrollmentProperties_attributes_enabled_b    certificateEnrollmentProperties_attributes_updated_d    ResultDescription   keyProperties_type_s    keyProperties_size_d    secretProperties_type_s certificateProperties_subject_s certificateProperties_sha1_s    certificateProperties_sha256_s  certificateProperties_nbf_t certificateProperties_exp_t Category    OperationName   ResultType  CallerIPAddress identity_claim_http_schemas_microsoft_com_identity_claims_objectidentifier_g    identity_claim_http_schemas_xmlsoap_org_ws_2005_05_identity_claims_upn_s    identity_claim_appid_g  id_s    clientInfo_s    requestUri_s    httpStatusCode_d    vaultProperties_s   ResourceId  OperationVersion    ResultSignature DurationMs  SubscriptionId  ResourceGroup   ResourceProvider    Resource    ResourceType    Type    _ResourceId

Answer (score 2):

If you want specific logs according to your application. You can use `<log-to-eventhub/>` in apim policy in the endpoint level / api level / product level.

Please see below link to know moer about this policy.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample.md

In policy, you will get all the request and response objects from `context` object.
Please see the link to know more about Context variables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables

For headers, you can lookup the dictionary object  `context.Request.Header`